# Казахские названия файлов при загрузке move_upload_file

Tags: php, upload, файлы

Я сделал загрузку файлов на php. Английские названия подгружаются корректно. Русские названия конвертировали они стали также конвертироваться корректно. А файлы с казахскими названиями вообще не загружает. Выдает ошибку про второй аргумент функции move_upload_file.

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\...\add_order.php on line 17

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpCFA6.tmp' to 'upload/' in C:\OpenServer\domains\...\add_order.php on line 17
```

Листинг:

```
<?php
/*Реализация загрузки файла*/
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";
echo "<h1>Загрузка новых файлов</h1>";
echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='add_order.php' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='10485760'>";
echo "<input name='file' type='file' multiple=''>";
echo "<p>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Загрузить файл'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
}else{
$uploaddir = 'upload/';
$filename = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $_FILES['file']['name']);
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir . $filename)){
    echo "Файл " . "<a href = 'upload/" . $_FILES['file']['name'] . "'>" . iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $filename) . "</a>" . " загружен";
  }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Добавить заказ</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вам надо не конвертацию кодировки делать, а транслитерацию букв в латинские символы и удаление недопустимых символов из имени файла.

Comment: Казахские символы в названии файла являются не только допустимыми, но и необходимыми. И тем более, мне не нужно делать транслитерацию казахского названия файла в английские символы. У меня загрузка русских и английских символов работает без проблем.

Comment: Тогда Вам проще везде использовать UTF-8. Многих казахских символов нет в cp1251.

Comment: У меня страница в utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам навязчиво подсказывают логи, вторым агрументом [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php) не может быть директория (должно быть имя файла). У вас вторым аргументом идет `upload/`, поскольку после `$filename = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $_FILES['file']['name']);` `$filename` становится пустым. Пустым оно становится потому, что [`iconv()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php) если встречает символ, который не может перевести в целевую кодировку, обрезает строку по этот символ. Видимо у вас в имени файла cразу встречается символ, которого нету в CP1251.

Замените строку на

```
$filename = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251//IGNORE", $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Однако, при этом вы все-равно потеряете символы, которых нету в CP1251. Чтобы создавать файлы в Windows c именами в Unicode (UCS-2LE), придется использовать разные хитрые лазейки (например COM-компонент `Scripting.FileSystemObject`).

Также хочу обратить ваше внимание, что перекодирование необходимо только если PHP скрипты выполняются в ОС Windows, поскольку сборка PHP для Windows использует однобайтовые функции доступа к файловой системе (например `CreateFileA()`) или если вы по какой-то причине в *NIX среде не можете использовать Unicode (и UTF-8 в частности). Если у вас скрипты выполняются на корректно настроенном хостинге - перекодирование имен не нужно. Достаточно отфильтровать имя файла (убрать символы `\x2f` и `\x00`).

Comment: Мммм, как все сложно, оказывается. Про фильтрацию спасибо. Как бы английские и русские символы загрузка спокойно отрабатывает. И в браузере и на диске создает корректные названия файлов. В данный момент работаю на локальном сервере созданном с помощью OpenServer. Вы считаете, что при заливке на хостинг, где стоят unix сервера проблема с utf-8 названиями казахских файлов исчезнет и это проблема только Windows машин? Вот к примеру, сервер mail.ru спокойно загружает и выгружает файлы с казахскими названиями. Как это? Нужно разбираться с Scripting.FileSystemObject?

Comment: Если будете выгружать ваш сайт на *NIX хостинг - перекодировка станет просто не нужна. А для Windows фильтровать придется больше символов. Windows API не любит в названиях файлов и директорий `<`, `>`, `:`, `"`, `/`, `\ `, `|`, `?`, `*`. См. [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)